# Finding the average time between two columns(VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I wish to convert the dates from each column to minutes, sum all the minutes and find the average time between each row. I have to fetch the data from a SQL database and display the final amount of minutes in a textbox.

Thanks for any help!

-Remi

Edit:
I solved this problem like this:
SELECT Datediff(minute, startdate, enddate) FROM «table-name»»)

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: DateSum = GetArray("SELECT Created, Behandlet FROM Behov WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN Created AND Behandlet) AND (DATEPART(MINUTE, DateAndTime) % 60 = 0) AND Valid = 1 AND Completed = 1", 2)(0, 0)
 
GetArray is the connection string to the DB.
 
DateAndTime does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
I solved this problem like this: SELECT Datediff(minute, startdate, enddate) FROM «table-name»»)